# how to deal with whispers/doubts?

Tags: salat, doubts

Salam

I've been having a problem recently with whispers,doubts and forgetfulness
In my salah i keep thinking i've forgotton to recite something or missed words etc from a surah or forgotten something else

When I'm reading islamic books or trying to memorise something i have the same problem
I try to block it out but i still struggle. how can i deal with this?

jazakallah

Comment: Does this help answer the question? https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68380/experiencing-waswas-or-ocd

Comment: jazakallah khair